# Binpacking / Merging problem where transfer is minimized

Tags: algorithm, merge, bin-packing

There are n boxes with a variable amount of identical items inside of it not exceeding 1728. The items can be moved from one box to another. The goal is to get boxes which have exactly 1728 items in order to get the minimal amount of boxes used.

However, each item transfer is time costly (takes 0.4 seconds). What would an algorithm (exact or approximation) to minimize the amount of item transfers done look like?

While this seems to be a simple variation of the binpacking problem, I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

I think it is because there is a bit of complexity in merging -- Lets say you have a box with 1727 items, and another with 1 item, it is more ideal to transfer that 1 item over to the 1727 item box rather than the other way around.

Moreover, I'm also interested in a variation of this problem where you can parallelize merging. EG: let's say there are m people who can move items from one box to another, each can do so individually from each other; However, they can't merge boxes being merged by another person.

Note: While this is an offline problem, the boxes are all available beforehand, it can also be an online problem where boxes come in continuously.

Comment: You could sort the boxes by number of balls, and repeatedly transfer balls from least-full non-empty box to most-full box with room left. You can stop when at most two boxes are partially filled.

Comment: Thats the algorithm I'm currently using, however, I'm not sure if it is exact. also, it does not work with parallel case.